# Scroll bar not appearing for a DIV element - ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to enhance a react app where the app doesn't have scroll bars by default and it need to be configured when required. I am having difficulty in setting up scroll bar to a div.

```
<React.Fragment>
    {/* HEADER POSITION FIXED  */}
    <Header />

    <div className={classes.MainContainer}>

        {/*OTHER COMPONENTS*/}
        <LeadInsertForm></LeadInsertForm>

    </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

I intend to set scroll bar to the MainContainer and was unable to do so. The .module.css file is as below:

```
.MainContainer {
    margin-top: 99px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

By doing above I was unable to see any scroll bar and the content getting trimmed off and getting hidden below the view port. I tried different combinations as `height: 100%` but no use.

The output is as below:

[image]

Can you please point out where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow-y: scroll` in the css.

If it doesn't work, try `overflow-y: scroll !important`
This should override any pre-existing css conflicting with this element.